# Add github library(BamTools) to c++ using cmake ExternalProject_Add

Tags: c++, git, cmake

I would like to use the BamTools library for a project. I am using CMake ExternalProject_Add to do this. CMake clones and compiles BamTools GitHub repo fine, but no matter what I try I can't get it to link properly. Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is my CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(myProject)
include(ExternalProject)

set( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-Wall -g")
set(BAMTOOLS_ROOT ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/bamtools)
set(BAMTOOLS_INCLUDE_DIRS ${BAMTOOLS_ROOT}/include/bamtools)
set(BAMTOOLS_LIBRARIES ${BAMTOOLS_ROOT}/lib/bamtools/libbamtools.a)
set(bamtools_INSTALL_DIR "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/external/bamtools")
set(bamtools_CMAKE_ARGS -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=${bamtools_INSTALL_DIR})

include_directories(${BAMTOOLS_INCLUDE_DIRS})

ExternalProject_Add(bamtools
  PREFIX ${BAMTOOLS_ROOT}
  GIT_REPOSITORY https://github.com/pezmaster31/bamtools
  BINARY_DIR ${BAMTOOLS_ROOT}
  INSTALL_DIR ${BAMTOOLS_ROOT}
  CMAKE_ARGS ${bamtools_CMAKE_ARGS}
)

add_subdirectory(src)
```

My simple main.cpp file exists in a src folder in the same directory as the CMakeLists.txt

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <api/BamReader.h>

using namespace BamTools;

int main(){
    BamReader reader =BamReader();
    reader.Close();
};
```

I get the following error

```
Linking CXX executable project
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_crc32", referenced from:
      BamTools::Internal::BgzfStream::DeflateBlock(int) in libbamtools.a(BgzfStream_p.cpp.o)
  "_deflate", referenced from:
      BamTools::Internal::BgzfStream::DeflateBlock(int) in libbamtools.a(BgzfStream_p.cpp.o)
  "_deflateEnd", referenced from:
      BamTools::Internal::BgzfStream::DeflateBlock(int) in libbamtools.a(BgzfStream_p.cpp.o)
  "_deflateInit2_", referenced from:
      BamTools::Internal::BgzfStream::DeflateBlock(int) in libbamtools.a(BgzfStream_p.cpp.o)
  "_inflate", referenced from:
      BamTools::Internal::BgzfStream::InflateBlock(unsigned long const&) in libbamtools.a(BgzfStream_p.cpp.o)
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      BamTools::Internal::BgzfStream::InflateBlock(unsigned long const&) in libbamtools.a(BgzfStream_p.cpp.o)
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      BamTools::Internal::BgzfStream::InflateBlock(unsigned long const&) in libbamtools.a(BgzfStream_p.cpp.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [src/project] Error 1
make[1]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/project.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: I think the problem is that Cmake is not pointing the executable to the library properly. It is expecting the library to be in the same directory as the executable. I tried using the dylib and to figure this out. `target_link_libraries` does not help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like the other answer said it was not linking ZLib properly. Making the following changes will resolve the issue. Instead of the `add_subdirectory(src)` add

```
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
add_library(libbamtools STATIC IMPORTED)
set_target_properties(libbamtools PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION ${BAMTOOLS_LIBRARIES}/libbamtools.a)
add_dependencies(libbamtools bamtools)

add_executable(myProject src/main.cpp)

include_directories(${BAMTOOLS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(myProject libbamtools ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES})
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are functions from zlib, I believe. You may need to explicitly link with zlib. Try adding `find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)`.

Comment: I can't get that to resolve the issue. I tried adding `find_package( ZLIB REQUIRED )
if ( ZLIB_FOUND )
    include_directories( ${ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIRS} )
    target_link_libraries( bamtools ${ZLIB_LIBRARIES} )
endif( ZLIB_FOUND )` after the external project add function